# sorting a vector pair by second element and then by first element in descending order when second element is equal

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, std-pair

imagine I have a pair {(1,0), (2,0), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1)} and I want to have it like {(3,1), (2,1), (1,1), (2,0), (1,0)}
after a sort by second element in descending order and then by the first element descending order.How can I do that?